# Nicht sich auf Gott beziehende Alternative für „Da sei Gott vor!“

Tags: idiom

Manchmal will ich meine echte und starke Unstimmigkeit zum Ausdruck bringen. Etwa

> Fall 1.
>   – *XY* Land will schon Todestrafe einführen.
>   – **Da sei Gott vor!**

Aber auch würde ich gerne –völlig ironisch wie in dieser Bildunterschrift der [taz](http://taz.de/index.php?id=bildergalerie&tx_gooffotoboek_pi1[srcdir]=Pegida&tx_gooffotoboek_pi1[fid]=4&cHash=9b3874b7d5c79f5b64f3731a7bc032ec)– spöttisch klingen können:

> Fall 2.
>   Blonde Frauen und Schleier? Da sei Gott vor!

Im ersten Fall klingt, als ob ich echt gläubig wäre (das will ich nicht), und im zweiten Fall klingt vielleicht viel zu spöttisch, so dass ich Gäubige  beleidigen könnte (das will ich auch nicht). Gibt's eine Variante?

Comment: Der Ausdruck scheint regional zu sein. Mir ist er zumindest unbekannt. Könntest du erläutern was an naheliegenden Alternativen wie "Hoffentlich nicht!" oder "Auch das noch!" nicht passt?

Comment: "Hoffentlich nicht!" ist in Ordnung. Der einzige Einwand, den ich da fände, wäre vielleicht, dass es  nicht so emotionel, leidenschaftlich, oder was auch immer wie "Da sei Gott vor!" klingt. Und "Auch das noch!" ist neu für mich. So, danke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schwierige Frage. Es gibt zwar Alternativen, aber die sind auch alle mit Gott oder Himmel. Das hat sich über Jahrhunderte in der christlichen Welt etabliert und es gab nicht wirklich den Bedarf nach Alternativen.
Das Problem beim Finden von Alternativen ist, dass man damit quasi die höchste Autorität anruft. Eine Formulierung gleicher "Stärke" zu finden, ohne den Schöpfer zu verwenden, kann nur fehlschlagen, denn welche Kraft sollte man anrufen.
Für die ironische Variante würde ich

> Bloß nicht!

vorschlagen.
Für das Erste finde ich das allerdings ein wenig zu flapsig.
Vielleicht könnte man sagen

> Das wäre eine Katastrophe./Alles, nur das nicht.

Aber das hat dann mit dem Original wirklich nur noch die persönliche Wertung gemein. Der Aspekt des Verhinderns fehlt.

(Natürlich kann man sagen: "Hoffentlich nicht", aber das ist nicht annähernd intensiv genug.)

Answer (score 2):

Eine etwas weniger scharfe Alternative für den zweiten Fall, die den ironischen Charakter erhält, wäre:

> Blonde Frauen und Schleier? Gott bewahre.

Für diesen Fall sehe ich aber keine "nicht-religiöse" Alternative, weil das ja gerade den Kontext parodiert.

Für den ersten Fall passt das aber nicht, weil es zu schwach ist (und "religiös" klingt). Vielleicht könnte man auch hier mit einer ironischen Bejahung den Effekt erzielen?

> Ein weiteres Land mit Todesstrafe? Das hat gerade noch gefehlt!

Das ist natürlich viel schwächer als "da sei Gott vor", aber beliebig steigerbar in der ironischen Spitze:

> Das ist ja ganz toll!
>   Auch das noch! (Hat @Harald schon vorgeschlagen.)
>   Das löst wirklich alle Probleme.
>   Da hat jemand aber mitgedacht!

(Ich bin gerade zu unkreativ, um noch bessere Ausdrücke zu finden, aber mit Ironie kann man eigentlich beliebige Grade der Schärfe erzielen.)